# Given a group action on a simplex, can I always find a fundamental region that is a simplex?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, group-actions, simplicial-complexes

Let $\Delta\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a simplex with $n+1$ vertices. Let $G\subset\mathrm{GL}(\Bbb R^n)$ be a finite group of linear symmetries of $\Delta$, i.e. linear transformations that fix the simplex set-wise. Set $m:=|G|$.

> **Question:**
> Is there a simplicial subdivision $\Delta=\Delta_1\cup\cdots\cup\Delta_m$,
> so that $G$ acts regularly (that is, transitively and freely) on the set of simplices $\{\Delta_i:1\le i\le m\}$?

In other words, I want a decomposition of $\Delta$ into fundamental regions w.r.t. the group  action, where each region is a simplex.
By *simplicial subdivision* I mean a tiling of $\Delta$ with simplices, any two of which are either disjoint or intersect in a common face (though their intersection with the boundary of $\Delta$ might not be a face of $\Delta$).

Such subdivisions clearly exist when $n=1$, and the image below shows that they also exist for $n=2$. The groups are (from left to right)

$$G\cong\text{$\{$ $\Bbb Z_2$,$\;$ the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_3$,$\;$ the dihedral group $D_3$}\}.$$

[image]

(update: simplicial subdivisions also exist for $n=3$; see Note II below)

Instead of thinking of $G$ as a linear group, we can interpret it as a permutation group $G\subseteq\mathbf S_{n+1}$, a subgroup of the symmetric group $\mathbf S_{n+1}$, permuting the vertices $\{1,...,n+1\}$ of $\Delta$.
The full symmetric group induces the *barycentric subdivision* (as seen in the right-most image).
One can then ask whether it is always possible to combine some of the simplices in the barycentric subdivision to form a simplex that is a fundamental region for $G$.

I also wonder in how far such a subdivision (if it exists) is unique (update: they are not, see Note II below).

---

**Note I**

In the comments I describe how to construct a decomposition for any group of order 2.

---

**Note II**

I found simplicial fundamental domains for all subgroups of $\mathbf S_4$ (subgroups taken from [here](http://faculty.smcm.edu/sgoldstine/Math321f09/S4subgroups.pdf)).

$$
\begin{array}{r|c|l}
\text{group} & \text{size} & \text{fundamental simplex} \\ 
\hline
\mathbf S_4 & 24 & \{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{1\} \\ \hline
\mathbf A_4 & 12 & \{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1\},\{2\} \\  \hline
\langle(1,2,3,4),(1,3)\rangle & 8
    & \{1,2,3,4\},\{1,3\},\{1\},\{2\} \\[-0.4ex]
  & & \{1,2\},\{2,4\},\{1,3\},\{1\} \\  \hline
\langle(1 2 3),(1 2)\rangle & 6
    & \{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{1\},\{4\} \\  \hline
\langle(1,2,3,4)\rangle & 4
    & \color{blue}{\{1,2,3,4\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}} \\[-0.4ex]
  & & \color{orange}{\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1\},\{2\}}
\\\hline
\langle(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4)\rangle & 4
    & \color{blue}{\{1,2,3,4\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}} \\  \hline
\langle(1,3),(2,4)\rangle & 4
    & \color{orange}{\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1\},\{2\}} \\  \hline
\langle(1,2,3)\rangle & 3
    & \{1,2,3\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\} \\  \hline
\langle(1,2)(3,4)\rangle & 2
    & \color{red}{\{1,2\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}} \\  \hline
\langle(1,2)\rangle & 2
    & \color{red}{\{1,2\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}} \\  \hline
\langle\varnothing\rangle & 1
    & \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}
\end{array}
$$

The groups are given as permutation groups on the vertex set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.
Each fundamental simplex is given in terms of its vertices, where a subset $S\subseteq\{1,2,3,4\}$ denotes the vertex

$$\frac1{|S|}\sum_{i\in S} v_i.$$

Simplices highlighted in the same color indicate that different groups have the same fundamental simplex.
I do not claim that the list of subdivisions is complete.

**Some oberservations:**

- There are groups (e.g. $\langle(1,2,3,4)\rangle$) that have two geometrically different subdivisions! So subdivisions are not always unique.
- A single subdivision can work for multiple groups (see the highlighted colors).
- The second fundamental simplex listed for the 8-element group is *not* a union of simplices from the barycentric subdivision! So there can exist other subdivision. But this subdivision still uses the same vertex coordinates as the barycentric subdivision.
- Curious observation (partially explained by David in the comments): the size of each group equals the product of the cardinalities of the sets listed in the right column. The reason seems to be that these cardinalities determine the volume of the fundamental simplex, which must be $|G|^{-1}\cdot\mathrm{vol}(\Delta)$.

Comment: Have you checked dimension 3? there are not so many subgroups of $S_4$ up to conjugacy.

Comment: Is it true for a group of order $2$ that is not generated by a transposition? There are not so many ways of subdividing a simplex into two simplices.

Comment: @Jemery This would be my attempt: if $G=\{\mathrm{id},g\}$ then choose a vertex $v_1\in\mathrm{vert}(\Delta)$ with $v_2:=gv_1\not= v_1$. Let $x$ be the mid-point of the edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then we can choose $\Delta_i$ to have vertices $\mathrm{vert}(\Delta)-\{v_1,v_2\}\cup\{v_i,x\}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard at least for a double transposition in dimension 3, it works easily.

Comment: @YCor Ah, OK. My geometric intuition stops working at around three dimensions!

Comment: @YCor I also cant see how it works for a double transposition. Let us say we look at the group $Z/2$ with nontrivial element $(0,1)(2,3)$. Then the vertices of the fundamental domain should be given by four vertices of the barycentric subdivision (which can be identified with nonempty subsets of 0,..,3). Could you provide that list?

Comment: My intuition would be that $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ should be in that list as the line through these vertices is fixed and then we should choose one of $\{0\},\{1\}$ and one of $\{2\},\{3\}$ and I think neither choice works. If I look at the tetrahedron along the fixed axis, the group action preserves each level set (orthogonal to that axis). If I intersect the middle plane with the four candidate fundamental domains, I get a square subdivided in four smaller squares and $G$ rotates the square by 180°. Neither of this smaller squares is a fundamental domain.

Comment: @Henrik As I tried to explain in my comment, the simplex $\{\{0,1\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ should work. You don't need to have $\{2,3\}$. The only thing that is forbidden is that only one of $2$ and $3$ is in the fundamental region.

Comment: I think your argument also shows that we can assume without loss of generality that $G$ acts transitively on the set of vertices. Otherwise pick a orbit of vertices with at least two elements, pick a simplex-fundamental domain for the sub-simplex $S$ spanned by these vertices. The whole simplex is the join of the subsimplex with the simplex $S'$ spanned by the other vertices. Taking the join of out fundamental domain with $S'$ should (hopefully) give a simplex fundamental domain for the entire simplex.

Comment: @Henrik I also expect (and hope) that something like this will turn out true. But I worry that it is more subtle. For example, both groups $\langle(1,2),(3,4)\rangle$ and $\langle (1,2)(3,4)\rangle$ act identically on their orbits, but the groups have different orders and therefore require different subdivisions.

Comment: I can get part way to explaining the observation about the products of the sizes of the sets. A set $S$ corresponds to the point $\tfrac{1}{|S|} \sum_{i \in S} e_i$ in the simplex. So, to compute the volume of the simplex corresponding to $S_1$, $S_2$,..., $S_n$, one computes the determinant of these vectors, and gets $\left( \prod \tfrac{1}{|S_i|} \right) \det M$ where $M_{ij}$ is $1$ if $j \in S_i$ and $0$ if $j \not \in S_i$. In every example so far, we have $\det(M) = 1$, so we just get $\prod \tfrac{1}{|S_i|}$.

Comment: It feels like we could order the simplex such that this matrix is upper triangular. My hope is that a fundamental domain needs one original vertex, then one vertex on an edge adjacent to that simplex, then one vertesx such that that edge with that new vertex is part of a 2-face and then one final one.

Comment: Indeed, in every case so far, we can reorder the rows and columns of $M$ to make $M$ upper triangular.

Comment: For the record, my bet is that the answer to the original question is "no", just on the grounds that there are a lot of subgroups of $S_n$ and they can be very complicated. But the data here suggests that there may be an interesting theory of cases where such a subdivision is possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is yes!

**Notation:** Let $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_n$ be the vertices of the simplex.
Let $[n] = \{ 1,2,3, \ldots, n \}$. For $S$ a nonempty subset of $[n]$, let $p(S) = \tfrac{1}{|S|} \sum_{i \in S} e_i$.

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$. Let $G_k$ be the subgroup of $G$ stabilizing (pointwise) each of $1$, $2$, ..., $k$. Let $A_k$ be the orbit of $k$ under the action of $G_{k-1}$.  Our fundamental domain will be the convex hull of $p(A_1)$, $p(A_2)$, ..., $p(A_n)$.

**Example** Take the third group in the OP's table, the dihedral group of order $8$. Then $A_1 = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$, $A_2 = \{ 2, 4 \}$, $A_3 = \{ 3 \}$, $A_4 = \{ 4 \}$ which, up to relabeling of coordinates, is the OP's first solution for this case.

Define a relation $\preceq$ on $[n]$ by $i \preceq j$ if $j \in A_i$.
In other words, $i \preceq j$ if there is $g \in G$ with $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=2$, ..., $g(i-1)=i-1$ and $g(i) = j$.

**Lemma** $\preceq$ is a partial order.

**Proof** It is clear that $i \in A_i$. If $j \in A_i$ then $i \leq j$, so it is clear that $\preceq$ is antisymmetric. It remains to check transitivity.

Suppose that $j \in A_i$ and $k \in A_j$. Note that $i \leq j$. The condition $k \in A_j$ means that $k \in G_{j-1} \cdot j \subseteq G_{i-1} \cdot j$. But the condition that $j \in A_i$ means that $G_{i-1} \cdot j = G_{i-1} \cdot i$. So we conclude that $k \in G_{i-1} \cdot i = A_i$, as desired. $\square$

**Lemma** Let $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ be a point of in the simplex. Then $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is in the convex hull of $p(A_1)$, $p(A_2)$, ..., $p(A_n)$ if and only if we have $x_i \leq x_j$ whenever $i \preceq j$.

**Proof** It is cleaner to work with $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$ and show that $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is a nonnegative linear combination of $p(A_1)$, $p(A_2)$, ..., $p(A_n)$ if and only if $x_i \leq x_j$ whenever $i \preceq j$.

Suppose first that $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is a nonnegative linear combination of $p(A_1)$, $p(A_2)$, ..., $p(A_n)$, and let us deduce that $x_i \leq x_j$ whenever $i \preceq j$. It is enough to show that, if $i \preceq j$, then $p(A_k)_i \leq p(A_k)_j$ for all $k$. If $k \leq i$, then $p(A_k)_i = p(A_k)_j$. If $k > i$ then $p(A_k)_i=0$ and $p(A_k)_j \geq 0$.

Now, suppose that $x_i \leq x_j$ whenever $i \preceq j$. In particular, $x_1 = \min_{i \in A_1} x_i = \min_{i \in G \cdot 1} x_i$. So we can write $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1 |A_1| p(A_1) + (0, y_2, \ldots, y_n)$ for some $(0, y_2, \ldots, y_n) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$, and we also have $y_i \leq y_j$ whenever $i \prec j$. We then induct, considering the group $G_1$ and the vector $(y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_n)$. $\square$

**Theorem** The convex hull of $p(A_1)$, $p(A_2)$, ..., $p(A_n)$ is a fundamental domain for $G$.

**Proof** Take a generic $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ in the simplex. We will show that there is a unique $g \in G$ such that $(gx)_i \leq (gx)_j$ if and only if $i \preceq j$. First of all, we must have $(gx)_1 = \min_{i \in G \cdot 1} (gx)_i$. So we must use $G$ to take the minimal element of $\min_{i \in G \cdot 1} x_i$ and move it to position $1$. We can do this, and once we do this we may only further apply elements of $G_1$. We then must similarly have $(gx)_2 = \min_{i \in G_1 \cdot 2} (gx)_i$; again, we can apply an element of $G_1$ to do this and then we are only permitted to apply elements of $G_2$. Continuing in this way, there is a unique element of $g$ which makes it so that $(gx)_i = \min_{j \in G_{i-1} \cdot i } (gx)_j$ for each $i$. $\square$

This concludes the proof that we have the fundamental domain as desired. We close by noting that, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, we have $|A_k| = |G_{k-1}|/|G_k|$ so $\prod_{k=1}^n |A_k| = \prod_{k=1}^n |G_{k-1}|/|G_k| = |G_0|/|G_n| = |G|/1 = |G|$, proving the curious observation in the question.

Comment: That is an amazing answer, thank you! Can you say a word or two about how you came up with this? Was it by looking hard at the examples in my post or are there some more underlying insights?

Comment: Beyond your examples, I also did the $10$ and $20$ element subgroups of $S_5$, the $21$ element subgroup of $S_7$ and worked out the general case of $C_p \ltimes C_q$ before I got it. I focused on groups that had few prime factors, since then the condition $\prod |A_j| = |G|$ was very restrictive, especially when combined with the condition that the determinant was nonzero.

Comment: For example, for the $10$ element subgroup of $S_5$, the only way to factor $10$ as a product of $5$ numbers each $\leq 5$ is $5 \times 2 \times 1 \times 1 \times 1$, and then only way to make the determinant nonzero is to use sets of the form $abcde$, $ab$, $a$, $c$, $d$. I noted that this worked if $e \equiv (a+b)/2 \bmod 5$, and not otherwise. I probably should have gotten it then, but it really clicked when I did the $21$ element subgroup of $S_7$. The sets had to be of the form $abcdefg$, $abc$, $a$, $b$, $d$, $e$, $f$, and it only worked when $abc$ was an orbit for $\text{Stab}(g)$.